# Espresso tests on Firebase Test Lab require "android.permission.DUMP"

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

When running a big test suite in Firebase Test Lab we're having the process killed for no reason.

After some forensic research, we've found a tragic line in Logcat that says `java.lang.SecurityException: Requires DUMP: Neither user 1001 nor current process has android.permission.DUMP`.

Does it ring someone's bell?

Comment: I've never run into such a problem with Firebase Test Lab. Did you look up DUMP permission and tried it on the test project?